# What is the most efficient way to implement mutable strings in C?

Tags: c, string

I'm currently implementing a *very simple* JSON parser in C and I would like to be able to use mutable strings (I can do it without mutable strings, however I would like to learn the best way of doing them anyway). My current method is as follows:

```
char * str = calloc(0, sizeof(char));
//The following is executed in a loop
int length = strlen(str);
str = realloc(str, sizeof(char) * (length + 2));
//I had to reallocate with +2 in order to ensure I still had a zero value at the end
str[length] = newChar;
str[length + 1] = 0;
```

I am comfortable with this approach, however it strikes me as a little inefficient given that I am **always** only appending one character each time (and for the sake of argument, I'm not doing any lookaheads to find the final length of my string). The alternative would be to use a linked list:

```
struct linked_string
{
    char character;
    struct linked_string * next;
}
```

Then, once I've finished processing I can find the length, allocate a `char *` of the appropriate length, and iterate through the linked list to create my string.

However, this approach seems memory inefficient, because I have to allocate memory for both each character and the pointer to the following character. Therefore my question is two-fold:

- Is creating a linked list and then a C-string faster than reallocing the C-string each time?
- If so, is the gained speed worth the greater memory overhead?

Comment: You shouldn't cast the return of the allocation functions, and you shouldn't feel the need to use `sizeof(char)`. That is `1` by definition, `malloc` and friends measure the sizes in terms of number of `char` they'd use.

Comment: one of the standard techniques is: every time you need to increase the size of your array, double it.

Comment: I'd only left the `sizeof` stuff because I had been some tests with `ints` and wide chars before I started using `strlen`. Will remove casts (not quite sure why I had them in the first place!)

Comment: If I see that right, you're creating a string like `a\0b\0c\0` instead of `abc\0`. Am I missing something, is this code incomplete, or is there a reason for that?

Comment: Code is incomplete @delnan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, linked lists are most certainly not "faster" (how and wherever you measure such a thing). This is a terrible overhead.

If you really find that your current approach is a bottleneck, you could always allocate or reallocate your strings in sizes of powers of `2`. Then you would only have to do `realloc` when you cross such a boundary for the total size of the `char` array.

Comment: I think this going to have to be the most sensible solution for my approach. Once I've finished 'processing' a string, would it be worth allocating a separate pointer of the correct length, copying the original string over and then freeing it in order to not have unused memory sitting around?

Comment: @ProgrammingThomas Given virtual memory and the data size to be expected, it's probably not worth it unless you're on a 32 bit machine and planning on reading files larger than a gigabyte. You can try giving back the excess memory with `realloc`.

Answer (score 4):

The standard way for dynamic arrays, regardless of whether you store `char`s or something else, is to *double* the capacity when you grow it. (Technically, any multiple works, but doubling is easy and strikes a good balance between speed and memory.) You should also ditch the 0 terminator (add one at the end if you need to return a 0 terminated string) and keep track of the allocated size (also known as *capacity*) and the number of characters actually stored. Otherwise, your loop has quadratic time complexity by virtue of using `strlen` repeatedly ([Shlemiel the painter's algorithm](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html)).

With these changes, time complexity is linear (amortized constant time per append operation) and practical performance is quite good for a variety of ugly low-level reasons.

The theoretical downside is that you use up to twice as much memory as strictly necessary, but the linked list needs at least five times as much memory for the same amount of characters (with 64 bit pointers, padding and typical malloc overhead, more like 24 or 32 times). It's not usually a problem in practice.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that it would be reasonable to read the entire set of text into one memory allocation, then go through and NUL terminate each string.   Then count the number of strings, and make a array of pointers to each of the strings.  That way you have one memory allocation for the text area, and one for the array of pointers.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't really an option in my case because I do actually need to process the strings and modify them - I might have something like \u002f or \/ that I would need to convert to a single / character rather than 2 or 6 characters.

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Most implementations of variable-length arrays/strings/whatever have a **size** and a **capacity**. The capacity is the allocated size, and the size is what's actually used.

```
struct mutable_string {
   char* data;
   size_t capacity;
};
```

Allocating a new string looks like this:

```
#define INITIAL_CAPACITY 10

mutable_string* mutable_string_create_empty() {
   mutable_string* str = malloc(sizeof(mutable_string));
   if (!str) return NULL;

   str->data = calloc(INITIAL_CAPACITY, 1);
   if (!str->data) { free(str); return NULL; }

   str->capacity = INITIAL_CAPACITY;

   return str;
}
```

Now, any time you need to add a character to the string, you'd do this:

```
int mutable_string_concat_char(mutable_string* str, char chr) {
   size_t len = strlen(str->data);
   if (len < str->capacity) {
      str->data[len] = chr;
      return 1; //Success
   }

   size_t new_capacity = str->capacity * 2;
   char* new_data = realloc(str->data, new_capacity);
   if (!new_data) return 0;

   str->data = new_data;
   str->data[len] = chr;
   str->data[len + 1] = '\0';
   str->capacity = new_capacity;
}
```

The linked list approach is worse because:

1. You still need to do an allocation call every time you add a character;
2. It consumes a *LOT* more memory. This approach consumes up to `sizeof(size_t) + (string_length + 1) * 2`. That approach consumes `string_length * sizeof(linked_string)`.
3. Generally, linked lists are less cache-friendly than arrays.

Comment: Due to the `strlen` call, your append method has linear time complexity. It's also inconsistent about return values (and honestly, I doubt that a return value is useful at all). I also believe this doesn't correctly add zero terminators at each step, so `len` would be off any time except right after resizing.

Comment: @delnan It's true that it is O(N). That can be fixed by adding a `size` field to the struct, which (I believe) is what most implementations do. As for adding the `\0`: `str->data[len + 1] = '\0';`. Is there any situation you believe would cause this to stop working? (Assuming concat_char is never called with chr='\0')